# Simple way of logging with Gunicorn and Flask on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask

The app is running on Heroku, but the issue when running is how to avoid the unhelpful error message of `Internal Server Error` and get more verbose error messages. For example, in the production environment, even with app.debug set to True, I still get no debug.

It would seem the smart thing to do, is to log everything to a file, but I don't see some working examples that do that. I simply want to write to a file for example. Is there any minimum working sample code that I can see that does this, outputting **application** errors?

Of course my app has the following settings:

```
app.run(debug = True)
```

My Procfile is:

```
web: gunicorn login:app
```

Answer (score 1):

Heroku will catch any log you send to STDOUT and STDERR and make it available in their logging pipeline: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging
You can then access your app's logs with the `heroku logs` command.

You can configure gunicorn to send logs to STDOUT with the `--log-file -` option.
See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn#adding-gunicorn-to-your-application-procfile

Comment: I can write manual comments - but I want to catch the errors from the application, however I cannot seem to do this with the settings above.